# ubuntu cmd tool to convert AAC ALAC APE WMA PKF audio to mp3

Tags: soundconverter

Please let me know any ubuntu command lint tools available to convert the audio formats AAC, ALAC, APE, WMA and PKF to MP3 format.
Can we get any reason If any cmd tools are not available for these audio formats.

Please share all the available information for these audio types.

Answer (score 0):

> Please share all the available information for these audio types.

That's a very ambitious request, and may take hundreds of pages to answer.
However each of the format you list has a Wikipedia file that you might

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey's_Audio
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Audio

While '.pkf' files are not audio files, they are metadata files:

- http://forums.adobe.com/thread/858022/

> let me know any ubuntu command lint tools available to
>   convert the audio formats

There are two types of media files: "containers" and "streams". A "container" file is a bit like a ZIP or 'tar' file, and is just a structured collection of sections. A "stream" file contains actual media data, encoded in some way, and may be embedded in a "container" file.

In general media formats of either type in GNU/Linux systems are handled by *libraries* that are often called "codec" libraries. These libraries provide the ability to encode and/or decode the media contained in those files.

The Wikipedia entry above mentions that `.ape` (Monkey's Audio) is supported by the `ffmpeg` library, and so most variants of WMA and ALAC conversions, and conversion is described in:

- [How to use Ffmpeg to convert wma to mp3 recursively, importing from txt file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508278/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-wma-to-mp3-recursively-importing-from-txt-file)
- [How do I convert music between formats and keep its metadata?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11116/how-do-i-convert-music-between-formats-and-keep-its-metadata/11441#11441)

PS: Searching Wikipedia and previous AskUbuntu questions often provides a lot of help.