# Script to convert .wma to .mp3 command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ffmpeg, mp3

I am using a script called `conv-script` that I found on AskUbuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508278/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-wma-to-mp3-recursively-importing-from-txt-file). It looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

readarray -t files < wma-files.txt

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=${file%.wma}.mp3
    probe=`avprobe -show_streams "$file" 2>/dev/null`
    rate=`echo "$probe" | grep "^bit_rate" | sed "s:.*=\(.*\)[0-9][0-9][0-9][.].*:\1:" | head -1`
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab "$rate"k "$out" && rm "$file"
done
```

I have ran `sudo chmod +x ./conv-script`
and then I try and execute it with `sudo ./conv-script`

After doing so I get an error `sudo: ./conv-script: command not found`

I am unsure what I am doing wrong as I can see the file in the current working directory and I have set it to be executable. One thing I thought it might be was the first line of my script is wrong, but I have another script with the same shebang and it executes fine. When I use the shebang in the original `#!/usr/bin/env bash` I get the same thing. Thanks for the help

EDIT:

output of `file conv-script`

`conv-script: a /usr/bin/env bash script, ASCII text executable`

output of `stat conv-script`

```
  File: ‘conv-script’
  Size: 325             Blocks: 64         IO Block: 32768  regular file
Device: 821h/2081d      Inode: 82004       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ kalenpw)   Gid: ( 1000/ kalenpw)
Access: 2016-05-17 16:40:43.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2016-05-17 14:33:31.000000000 -0600
Change: 2016-05-17 14:33:32.000000000 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `file conv-script` and `stat conv-script`.

Comment: First, you do not need sudo is all of the above. Second, make sure to cd to the location of the script, for example, `cd Downloads` or `cd Music`.

Comment: Don't use `sudo`.  @mikewhatever, he's already in the right directory because `chmod` is not failing.

Comment: I was using sudo because without sudo I get "bash: ./conv-script: Permisson denied" I have editted in the output for those 2 commands. @muru

Comment: It looks like your `chmod` didn't take effect. Is this script on a NTFS partition?

Comment: @muru It is on a FAT 32 partition

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, `chmod` can fail silently on Windows partitions. (@muru, it's funny, I just came here to post that before you commented.)

Comment: You'll have to remount the partition with correct options. See linked post. Similar settings apply for FAT32, where the filesystem type is `vfat` instead of `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: Could also move the script to an EXT partition, if there's one readily available.

Comment: Hmm. Had no idea chmod didn't work on different partition types today I learned, thanks. I ended up following wjandrea's suggestion and moving it to an EXT partition and the script is in progress right now and appears to be working

Comment: Your title says "WAV", but your script has "WMA". Which is the correct one? Reusing the bitrate from the input file is a bad idea: your inputs and outputs are completely different formats, even if they were the same not all encoder implementations are the equal in terms of compression efficiency, and how do you know that they were encoded by a sane person who knows what they are doing? Use a quality based rate control method instead. See [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard oops didn't even notice the title was wrong it should be WMA.  Damn I've already started hopefully they play fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first make sure you have `ffmpeg` and `libav-tools` installed, this you can do by typing in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
apt-cache policy ffmpeg libav-tools
```

This should get you an output like the following if both are installed:

```
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libav-tools:
  Installed: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If you get in one of the lines beginning with `Installed:` an entry `(none)` install the package with `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`.

Now only a few corrections to the script itself:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"
find . -type f | grep wma$ > wma-files.txt

readarray -t files < wma-files.txt

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    out=${file%.wma}.mp3
    probe="$(avprobe -show_streams "$file" 2>/dev/null)"
    rate="$(echo "$probe" | grep "^bit_rate" | sed "s:.*=\(.*\)[0-9][0-9][0-9][.].*:\1:" | head -1)"
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab "$rate"k "$out" && rm "$file"
done
```

You can call this then with `./script.sh /path-to-your-music`.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have libav-tools installed but after installing that and fixing the script I still get the same Permission denied message.

Comment: Well as i read from the comments on your question this is more a problem of remounting the partition properly. But your command not found error should be past now.

Comment: yeah that was the issue I had no idea it couldn't be mounted as FAT but I needed libav-tools anyway so thank you

Comment: `libav-tools` is just a transitional package that installs the `ffmpeg` package, so it can be ignored if you install `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard and why then `avprobe`doesnt show up even if i have `ffmpeg`installed? Ad why does `apt-cache search avprobe` yields as output this package? I test each answer I write on my machine before and without `libav-tools` the script didn't work.