# Converting WMA music files to WAV format

Tags: 14.04

I have a lot of .wma files which Iam trying to convert to .wav format so that I can use the K3B app to burn them into an audio CD.  K3B works fine in creating and burning audio cds  as long as the input files are in .wav format.

I installed Sound converter and it says " Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: Windows Media Audio 8 decoder", when I tried to convert.

I opened synaptic package manager and it says gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly is there and installed.
What other plugins do I need to install here to get it to work?

thanks

Comment: I forgot. I use Trusty Tahr 14.04 version of ubuntu.

Comment: If you fancy using ffmpeg, [here](http://grumpyuzhiel.blogspot.de/2012/06/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-to-audio-cd.html) is a quick quide

Comment: See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/508278/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-convert-wma-to-mp3-recursively-importing-from-txt-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611180/ffmpeg-wma-to-wav

Comment: Trusty does not come packaged with ffmpeg.  I got a "command not found" on the terminal.  Then googled and found out it is so.  Some thing called libav has been its replacement.  Anybody know how to use that.  Apparently 15.05 now has ffmpeg back in the basic package.

Comment: In the process of installing ffmpeg, I managed to get the Sound Converter  app working as follows.  The procedure to install ffmpeg is given in the following link :  (https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/).  If you follow the procedure given there, it will install ffmpeg, and update a whole bunch of packages as well which incidentally fullfils the requirement of Sound Converter.  So the process of installing ffmpeg made the  Sound Converter app work. Thanks.